# Posting a form from jquery's autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys having a small issue that my dropdown loses focus when one of the options is clicked. I would like to submit the form when the dropdown is clicked; here is my code:

```
    $(function() {

            var availableTags = [
                "Thing",
                "Thing2",
                "Thing3"];

            $( "#searchbox" ).autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
            });

    });
```

What I would like to do is submit my form when one of the dropdowns is selected from auto-complete.

**EDIT:**

Forgot my HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="search" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        <input id='searchbox' class='ui-widget' type='text' name="search" size="30" />
        <button type="submit"/>Search</button>

      </form>
```

**EDIT2:**
And my AJAX post function although its not really relavent:

```
$("#search").submit(function(event) {
    /* Stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();
    /* Clear result div*/
    $("#result").html('');
    /* Get some values from elements on the page: */
    var values = $(this).serialize();
    /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
    $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/search.inc.php",
            type: "post",
            data: values,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#result").html(data);
            }
    });
});
```

**EDIT3:**
Thanks Ehsan, my result:
            $(function() {

```
            var availableTags = [
                "my php for tags"];

                    $( "#searchbox" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            select: function(event, ui) 
            {
            $("#search").submit();
            }
        });

    });
```

**EDIT4:**
Ahh problem is it posts the form but posts it with just the query typed not the autocomplete :/. ie. I type "T" and click on "T100" and it only posts "T".

**EDIT5:**
Thanks to AndrewPolland for solution to my latest problem:

```
$( "#searchbox" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#searchbox").val(ui.item.value);
        $("#search").submit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using something very similar at the moment. You can use `select` in the autocomplete setup and then submit the form using `submit()`.

E.g.

```
$( "#searchbox" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#search").submit();
    }
});
```

---

Looking at the update to your question. You could also move the ajax submit code into a separate function and call it on selecting an option. The above is probably the best option though.

E.g.

```
function formSubmit(){
    /* Clear result div*/
    $("#result").html('');
    /* Get some values from elements on the page: */
    var values = $(this).serialize();
    /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/search.inc.php",
        type: "post",
        data: values,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#result").html(data);
        }
    });
}

$( "#searchbox" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        formSubmit();
    }
});

$("#search").submit(function(event) {
    /* Stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault();
    formSubmit();
});
```

As I said though, the first option is probably the best. Just included this in case it's more appropriate for your case.

---

To solve your "Edit4" problem. Try the following:

```
$( "#searchbox" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#searchbox").val(ui.item.value);
        $("#search").submit();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `select` property of **autocomplete**, its function is fired when user selects an option from autocomplete:

```
$( "#searchbox" ).autocomplete({
                source: availableTags,
                select: function(event, ui) 
                {
                $("form").submit();
                }
            });
```

### UPDATE:

Make hidden field in form:

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="search" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        <input type="hidden" id="selectedValue"/>
        <input id='searchbox' class='ui-widget' type='text' name="search" size="30" />
        <button type="submit"/>Search</button>

      </form>
```

Set its value on select like this and post form:

```
$( "#searchbox" ).autocomplete({
                    source: availableTags,
                    select: function(event, ui) 
                    {
                    $('#selectedValue').val(ui.item.value);
                    $("form").submit();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Ahh problem is it posts the form but posts it with just the query typed not the autocomplete :/. ie. I type "T" and click on "T100" and it only posts "T".

Comment: Thanks buddy, you and andrew were so much help =)